# Convert JSON to hash map with Jackson- Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Before this is marked as a duplicate please read the question (I did look at similar ones). Thank you.

For simplicity, assume I have JSON like this:

```
{
   "clients" : [
   {
      "name" : "client 1",
      "id" : 1
   },
   {
      "name" : "client 2",
      "id" : 2
   }
],
   "other" : {
      "something" : ""
   }

   ...
}
```

So I want to create a hash map of only the clients and their fields. The basic question is how would I go about doing this using Jackson methods for a single JSON array like clients? I've tried to look online but all of the examples that I have seen either don't use Jackson or only are for a single JSON object like so:

```
HashMap<String, String>[] values = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>[]>() {});
```

I've also seen Gson examples and I know I can do some string parsing magic:

```
jsonSting = jsonString.substring(jsonString.indexOf("["), (jsonString.indexOf("]")+1))
```

to get it in a format that I can use, but I want to try it with Jackson to avoid importing another library. Any ideas?

---

Rephrasing the question: 
So if I only had a list of clients like so:

```
jsonString = [{"name" : "client 1","id" : 1},{"name" : "client 2","id" : 2}]
```

then I could just do:

```
HashMap[] values = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference[]>() {});
```

to get what I want. I am basically asking if there is a way using Jackson methods to get the jsonString above from the large JSON section on top. I know I can easily do it with this example with string parsing but there will be more complex situations in the future and string parsing is not really considered best practice

Comment: Please describe the target hashmap. What are its keys? What are its values?

Comment: u have the API , search the example , give it a shot

Comment: It's an array of hash maps so each client would have its own map (It makes more sense to use for a larger data set). So for the first client the keys would be name and id, and the values would be "client 1" and 1

Comment: So you want an array of hashmaps?

Comment: It's a little complicated, I will need it for other parts of a large project to compare results with database queries and to keep track of how many clients there are.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you want to get from the json. How do you go from the json you've shown to the hashmap you're requesting.

Comment: So if I only had a list of clients like so: jsonString = [{"name" : "client 1","id" : 1},{"name" : "client 2","id" : 2}], then I could just do: HashMap[] values = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference[]>() {}); to get what I want. I am basically asking if there is a way using Jackson methods to get the jsonString above from the JSON in the original question. I know I can easily do it with this example with string parsing but there will be more complex situations in the future and string parsing is not really considered best practice.

Comment: Please add all that to your question and format it. It's hard to read in comments.

Comment: Okay, I made the changes.

Comment: No, the JSON will be a Java string. It is the return value of a query from a database.

Comment: Is there are reason for using a `HashMap` rather than a POJO?

Comment: Not particularly, as long as I can do comparisons. I'll take a look at POJOs, I haven't worked too much with them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract a part of the JSON tree using [the Jackson tree model API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel) and then convert it to an array of maps.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonReadPart {
    public static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "   \"clients\" : [\n" +
            "   {\n" +
            "      \"name\" : \"client 1\",\n" +
            "      \"id\" : 1\n" +
            "   },\n" +
            "   {\n" +
            "      \"name\" : \"client 2\",\n" +
            "      \"id\" : 2\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "],\n" +
            "   \"other\" : {\n" +
            "      \"something\" : \"\"\n" +
            "   }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(JSON).path("clients");

        // non type safe
        Map<String, Object>[] clients = mapper.treeToValue(node, Map[].class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clients));

        // type safe
        JsonParser parser = mapper.treeAsTokens(node);
        clients = parser.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>[]>() {});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clients));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[{name=client 1, id=1}, {name=client 2, id=2}]
[{name=client 1, id=1}, {name=client 2, id=2}]
```